# Updating N joined EF entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following design question. There are multiple scenarios when we need to use entity objects that do not map directly to our data store. In order to SELECT data for those object we can use JOINs in LINQ but updating such an entity leads to multiple table updates that have to be written manually.
Is there some magic that can be done with EF, so that I define that my custom entity is composed by N data store entities and I can update all N entities with a single SaveChanges() ? (same holds for inserts)

Comment: Add more details about your model. Entities and relationships.

Comment: For example you are using a new entity in your presentation layer that is composed of parts of 3 entities coming from your DB connected with FK relationships. You display this information and then you want to update fields in 2 of those 3 entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
context.DetectChanges();
context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
```